# How to make buttons disappear if another button is hovered in bootstrap3?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have implemented multiple buttons in bootstrap 3 . The idea is that a series of buttons open up if a particular button is hovered over by the mouse. In the following code when the "Water" button is hovered over it displays buttons "1,2,4" but when i hover or click on "a" they don't disappear. i want that when any other button from "a,bb2,c,d,ee2" is hovered over, only its child buttons are displayed and any other previously displayed buttons are hidden from the screen. How can this be done?
https://jsfiddle.net/tnj6zLos/1/

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create_tab').tab('show')
    })

    
    $('#login_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#login_tab').tab('show')
    })

     $('#create_btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#create1_tab').tab('show')
    })
    $(".hover_btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    
    $(".hover_btn").mouseenter(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1default").css("opacity","1");
    })
   
     
    $(".hover_btn2").hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","1");
    })
    
    $(".hover_btn2").mouseleave(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab2default1").css("opacity","0");
    })

});
```

```css
 #customTab a {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .flex {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: baseline;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        @media (max-width: 576px) {
            .container {
                padding: 0;
            }

            .btn {
                padding: 3px 6px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default{
                margin-right: 4px;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-heading{
                padding: 0;
            }
            .flex .panel-default>.panel-body .btn:last-child{
                margin-top: 4px;
            }
        }

        .btn-dark {
            background-color: #343a40;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .btn-dark:hover,.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .btn.focus, .btn:focus,.btn:active,.btn:hover , .active >a .btn{
            color: #fff;
            background: blue;
        }
        .nav-tabs{
            border: none;
        }
        
        .hover_btn{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
        }
        
        .hover_btn:hover{
            background-image: url(air.jfif);
            background-size: cover;
            color: #000;
            height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
   <div><br></br>Some text.</div>
        <div class="container" id="customTab">
            </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
                        <li><span class="btn btn-info btn-lg ">main heading</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br></br>
        <div class="container" id="customTab">
                    <ul class="nav " style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; border: none;">
                        <li><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab" id="test"><span class="hover_btn" >Water</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                    class="btn btn-info">aaaa</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3default" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                    class="btn btn-info">b<br>b2</br>
                                     </span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab4default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">c</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab5default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">d</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab6default" data-toggle="tab"><span class="btn btn-info">e<br>e2</br>
                             
                            
                        </span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content hover_btn2">
                    <div class= "hover_btn2" >
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab1default"  >
                            <div class="flex ">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">1</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                              
                                <div class=" panel-default">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li a id="login_btn"><span class="btn btn-info" data-target="#signin" data-toggle="modal">2</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="signin" role="dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="well">
                                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                <li class="active"><a id="login_tab" href="#login" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
                                                <li class=""><a id="create_tab" href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a></li>
                                                <li class=""><a id="create1_tab" href="#create1" data-toggle="tab">Workflows</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                            
                                            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content ">
                                                <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
                                               <iframe src= "" style="border:none;width:1450px;height:600px;" >
                                           
                                               </iframe>     
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade.in" id="create">
                                                 <p>
                                                 hello
                                                 </p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade.in" id="create1">
                                                 <p>
                                                 hellosss
                                                 </p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>    

                                   
                                </div>
                                <div >
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li href="#tab2default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">4</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <br></br>
                                        <div class="flex tab-pane fade" id="tab2default3">
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                        <li href="#tab22default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                                    class="btn btn-info">4</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                              
                                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                                        <li href="#tab222default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                                    class="btn btn-info">5</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                               
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default1" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">6</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default1">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal7">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal8">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">7</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal9">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal10">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab3default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">8</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal11">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal12">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3default">
                            <div class="flex">
                          
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab5default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">9</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal21">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal22">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab5default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">10</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab5default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal23">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal24">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4default">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default1" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">11</span></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default1">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal25">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal26">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default2" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">12</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal27">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal28">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#tab6default3" data-toggle="tab"><span
                                                        class="btn btn-info">13</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab6default3">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal29">Workflow</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#myModal30">Reviews</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

create a button with an id exemple:
closing button

then with your javaScript scope the element and hide the buttons (took the way you hide from your code)

```
$("#closeButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1default").css("opacity","0");
})
```

Comment: i dont want to have a close button on the display. is there a way to implement this without creating a proper button or without displaying the close button?

Comment: hum if the button appear with the 123 elements its not on the display but once you showed the buttons? you need to put the button inside the div you put in opacity 1 when hovering water button

Comment: sorry i could not understand what you have written . could you explain with an example from my code?

Comment: well you have to add the button somewhere inside your div with id tab1default, where? it depends where you want it to be..